# PowerPoint slide sorter / editor keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint

whats the keyboard shortcut to go to (and from?) the slide sorter and the editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> in PowerPoint 2010 will switch you from Normal to Slide Sorter View and back again.

Answer (score 6):

With PowerPoint 2010, you can do <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> then:

- <kbd>I</kbd> to go to the slide sorter
- <kbd>L</kbd> to go back to the normal view

You could also add the slide sorter and normal view to the "quick access toolbar", and then access them with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> (depends on the order of the toolbar).

Answer (score 3):

Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in "Slide Show" mode will bring up a modal window with the list of slides. You can then select the slide you wish to jump to. Pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> in "Slide Show" mode will bring up a modal window with the list of shortcuts (including this one). I hope this helps.

Comment: i want to move between the slide sorter and the slide editing view at design time - not during a presentation!

Answer (score 2):

There's a two step solution to adding a keyboard shortcut for toggling between **Slide Sorter View** and back to **Normal View**.

1. Select View > and right click Slide Sorter. Select Add to Quick Access Toolbar. This adds the Slide Sorter key to your Quick Access Toolbar, obviously!
2. Once step 1 is completed, you can then initiate the new quick access button by using Alt + 'x' (where x stands for the position of the Slide Sorter Quick Access button in the Quick Access Toolbar). For example Alt + 4.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Just to avoid confusion <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> DOES NOT switch to slide sorter view. It starts the fifth item on the QAT. This MAY be slide sorter view.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much restricted to <kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to move clockwise and counter-clockwise through the various panes.

You could perhaps look at defining an action for this with [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: these keys dont seem to change the view. Is it possible to create such a shortcut key?

Comment: Edited my answer - you could perhaps look into AutoHotKey.

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint 2016: Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, you should see a prompt for the next key for old-fashion drop-down menu command. Then press <kbd>D</kbd> to switch to the Slide Sorter view or back to Normal view.